# Invalid command 'PerlRequire', perhaps misspelled

Tags: apache

I have got this error when we configure and restart apache ? Invalid command 'PerlRequire', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have more information. ...fail! –